# MongoDB query issue: ISODate().getTime() is not working in mongo web

Tags: mongodb

I'm facing the problem below:

Query: **{date: {$lte: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 3)}}**

1. The same query, executed error thru mongo Atlas web, but in compass, it's working.
2. I'm trying to all get the data and exclude the data in past 2 days(include today).
3. I'm using Mongo DB 5.0.
4. Both of the query are connect to the same DB endpoint.

[image: Image 1]
I execute the query in mongo atlas web, and having error.

[image: Image 2]
Then I try run the same query in Compass, without any issue.

Any clue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: `ISODate()` is a helper function in the **mongo shell**. `new Date()` is a JavaScript function (the mongo shell is also a JavaScript runtime). It depends on the tool which you use, whether these functions are implemented or not.